# Best practices for a change of email/user

Tags: email, user-communication

Our website uses a system where the username is the user's email address. We have a function which permits the user to change his email.

What is the best way to go about this?

- Send an email **only** to the new email address just to **confirm** the change.
- Send an email to **both** the new and the old email addresses for **confirmation**.
- Send an email to the new address, asking the user to click a button for **activation**.
- I'm open to any different suggestions as well.

I'm concerned about functionality, security and usability. There could be some problems with activation; for example, activating an email address that has been created between the change request and the changed email activation would certainly cause some problems. I'm probably forgetting other corner cases...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The most common way is to:

1. Ask the user to enter her password before changing e-mail (even if she is currently logged in): this will help to avoid stealing of the account if user has forgotten to logout or somebody simply got user's cookies or something like this.
2. Send an activation link to the *new* address and don't switch e-mails until the new one will be activated: this will ensure that user has entered the correct e-mail address she has access to.

Comment: Instead of step 2, you can make the change but send a notification to the previous email address with link provide to undo/reset the action if required. This removes a barrier for the majority of use cases (genuine change of email, not malicious).

Comment: @RedSirius but you will not be sure the new e-mail is valid in that case, and what if there is a typo in the e-mail address?

Comment: You can still send a notification to the new address, just not require the activation step :)

Comment: @alexeypegov's answer seems ticks the box for both security and validation. You need to confirm the account to prevent users setting up the wrong email address. A notification won't do this. I doubt that the user will even read it correctly.

Comment: @RedSirius What if the user is changing the email address because their old one has been hijacked?

Comment: An old thread, but something that is worth mentioning is that Credential Stuffing attacks (ATO) are very common and successful in 2020 due to password reuse and improperly stored credentials. If an activation link is sent to the new address and that new address is owned by the threat actor you are enabling them to take over the account.

It is much more likely that the account will be compromised before the old email. I would rather have a confirmation be sent to the old email with a notification sent to the new email after confirming the change.

Comment: some are saying confirmation to old, some are saying confirmation link to the new email, i have a better idea, before changing email, ask old email password, new email, send confirmation link to new email, user clicks on it from their new email, now they need to login with new email address and password, this way even if an attacker owned the new email address he wont be able to login

Comment: @PirateApp Could you please rephrase your thought process? I am a little bit confused. Why would the attacker not be able to login even if the new email address is owned by the attacker?

You say: Ask for old password (to activate email change) > Enter new email > Send confirmation link to new email > Receiver clicks on the activation link in the new email > Now user has to log in again (implying that the old session was destroyed). How does this protect agains attacker if the attacker knows the old password and changes the email? It doesn't.

Comment: @ScotMatson but what happens when the user wants to change their email address because they lost access to their old email address? According to your solution the user will then never be able to change their email address.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion these steps should be secure and user friendly enough:

1. Ask for password confirmation in the form to prevent other people to change the email address when someone forgot to logout.
2. Send an email to the old email address to let the user know that is has been changed and offer the possibility to prevent or revert the change.
3. Send an email to the new email address to verify the email address.
4. When the user verifies the new email address, change the old email address to the new one but keep the old one in case it needs to be reverted. To check if the old email address is actually the previous one you should save it somewhere.

Comment: how does this work if your user used Facebook to login on your website and doesnt have a password?

Comment: Good question, I would say that the user should confirm the change with their new email address and the user should still get a warning on their old email address and be able to revert te change I think. Do you have other suggestions? @PirateApp

Comment: the same point is applicable to the socially logged in user as well no? what if you are logged in and away from your workstation and someone else tries updating your email. in the case of normal login, you would ask for a password, what will you do here?